# weka StringToWordVector limit word length

Tags: weka

Using StringToWordVector filter in weka, how can I limit the length of the words (for example, leave only words containing at least two characters)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can do it with a standard StringToWordVector. But you could implement your own filter. Since what you are going to do is not much different from what StringToWordVector class does, you could just inherit it and override method [input](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/Filter.html#input%28weka.core.Instance%29).

Here is an example of using filter in a code from [documentation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/Filter.html):

```
  Filter filter = new MyStringToWordVector();
  Instances instances = ..some instances..
  for (int i = 0; i < data.numInstances(); i++) {
    filter.input(data.instance(i));
  }
  filter.batchFinished();
  Instances newData = filter.outputFormat();
  Instance processed;
  while ((processed = filter.output()) != null) {
    newData.add(processed);
  }
  ..do something with newData..
```

alternatively you can use StringToWordVector instead of your filter, but change filtering part of the above code in the following way:

```
StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();
int attrNum = Integer.parseInt(filter.getAttributeIndices()); 
for (int i = 0; i < data.numInstances(); i++) {
    Instance instance = data.get(i);

    String str = instance.stringValue(attrNum);
    // Apply your logic here
    if (str.length > 2) {
         filter.input(data.instance(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like removing attributes using "RemoveByName" filter can do the trick after applying StringToWordVector filter . This filter removes attributes based on a regular expression matched against their names.